# Android - Switch button to only change state through sliding

Tags: android, android-widget, slider, touch, android-sliding

The switch button that android has is really cool. I want to  have the switch change states only through the only the sliding motion. What I don't want it to do is to change states when just tapping the switch. I would also like to be able to keep the nice sliding animation in tact. Does anyone know how to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by ensuring the switch is not clickable

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

and then adding touch listener that passes touch events to the switch

```
        final Switch switch = 
                   (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lock_switch);
        if (switch != null) {
            // This combined with android:clickable="false"
            // makes this a slide only switch
            switch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```